# porque el navegador no esta compliando el codigo y muestra el coodigo en la pantalla

Tags: php7

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con PHP y me esta generando el siguiente error y es que cuando cargo una vista aparece es el código como un texto en en el navegador cabe destacar que es solo esa vista el resto del proyecto si esta visualizándose sin fallas ojala me puedan colaborar estoy trabajando con apache version 7.4

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

¿chequeaste que estubiera encerrado entre etiqueta de php?

Lo más seguro es que el código no seesté interpretando por esa razón se te muestra como texto plano y no como un código a ejecutar.

Tambien puedes revisar la extensión del archivo que se está ejecutando